# Count frequency of combinations of elements in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

[image]

What I want to do is to count the frequency of combination of elements. For example:

- umbrella appears 8 times in the whole df
- detergent appears 5 times
- (beer, diaper) appear 2 times
- (beer, milk) appear 2 times
- (umbrella, milk, beer) appear 2 times

and so on, in other words, I need to generate something like this:
[image]

Count all the frequencies of single and combined items and only keep those both single and combined items with frequency >= n, where n is any positive integer. For this example let's say n -> {1, 2, 3, 4}.

I've been trying to use the following code:

```
# candidates itemsets
records = []

# generates a list of lists of products that were bought together (convert df to list of lists)
for i in range(0, num_records):
    records.append([str(data.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, len(data.columns))])
    
# clean list (delete NaN values)
records = [[x for x in y if str(x) != 'nan'] for y in records]

OUTPUT:
[['detergent'],
 ['bread', 'water'],
 ['bread', 'umbrella', 'milk', 'diaper', 'beer'],
 ['detergent', 'beer', 'umbrella', 'milk'],
 ['cheese', 'detergent', 'diaper', 'umbrella'],
 ['umbrella', 'water', 'beer'],
 ['umbrella', 'water'],
 ['water', 'umbrella'],
 ['diaper', 'water', 'cheese', 'beer', 'detergent', 'umbrella'],
 ['umbrella', 'cheese', 'detergent', 'water', 'beer']]
```

and then:

```
setOfItems = []
newListOfItems = []
for item in records:
    if item in setOfItems:
        continue
    setOfItems.append(item)
    temp = list(item)
    occurence = records.count(item)
    temp.append(occurence)
    newListOfItems.append(temp)

OUTPUT:

['detergent', 1]
['bread', 'water', 1]
['bread', 'umbrella', 'milk', 'diaper', 'beer', 1]
['detergent', 'beer', 'umbrella', 'milk', 1]
['cheese', 'detergent', 'diaper', 'umbrella', 1]
['umbrella', 'water', 'beer', 1]
['umbrella', 'water', 1]
['water', 'umbrella', 1]
['diaper', 'water', 'cheese', 'beer', 'detergent', 'umbrella', 1]
['umbrella', 'cheese', 'detergent', 'water', 'beer', 1]
```

As you can see, it is only counting the freq of the whole row (from image 1), however my expected output is the one that appears in the second image.

Comment: Currently your `item` is a list of items and not a single item, you probably want to use two for-loops. Try to get it correct for one element first and the increase for higher levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem! I am using `itertools.combinations()` to generate all possible combinations and `collections.Counter()` to count for every combination how often it appears:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from collections import Counter

# create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['detergent', np.nan],
    ['bread', 'water', None],
    ['bread', 'umbrella', 'milk', 'diaper', 'beer'],
    ['umbrella', 'water'],
    ['water', 'umbrella'],
    ['umbrella', 'water']
])

def get_all_combinations_without_nan_or_None(row):
    # remove nan, None and double values
    set_without_nan = {value for value in row if isinstance(value, str)}
    
    # generate all possible combinations of the values in a row
    all_combinations = []
    for i in range(1, len(set_without_nan)+1):
        result = list(itertools.combinations(set_without_nan, i))
        all_combinations.extend(result)
        
    return all_combinations
    
# get all posssible combinations of values in a row
all_rows = df.apply(get_all_combinations_without_nan_or_None, 1).values
all_rows_flatten = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_rows))

# use Counter to count how many there are of each combination
count_combinations = Counter(all_rows_flatten)
```

Docs on `collections.Counter()`: 
 https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Docs on `itertools.combinations()`: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: It does exactly what I want, however I'm trying to understand your code. I already know what ``` itertools.combinations() ``` is doing. I was actually using it but I think I am using it in a different way. What I'm doing whit ``` itertools.combinations() ``` is to pass the list of lists I generated (is not actually doing what I want) but I see you are using it with *set_without_nan* but is not very clear what is inside of this variable. Can you help me?

Comment: if you want to understand what is happening or what variables look like, i think it is always handy to add print statements, so in the function get_all_cominations() just add print(row) and print(set_without_nan) etc, and you can see what it does. It basiscally gets the row of the dataframe, loops over all values and only keeps the unique values that are not nan. Then itertools.combinations creates a list with all possible combinations of the words in a row. Using print statements of your variables helps a lot to make things clearer :)